# When Importing Java Project Directory, eclipse is not properly creating sub directories for bin and SRC

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, importerror

When Importing Java Project Directory, eclipse is not properly creating sub directories for bin and SRC. It is taking src as a part of package name.

Eg: importing the directory which has Bin and SRC folders. but it is not creating the structure as expected. [![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is the file structure:[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Please advice on how to effectively import the folder.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaGkT.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2qT9.png

Comment: Add it manually and move on.  Eclipse isn't very smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.classpath` file, which tells it that `src` should be treated as a Java Source Folder, is missing.